# user.update rollback error in model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As everything working as expected, i'm trying to save the new values in the database but i'm getting a rollback error on update

my **model.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

   before_update :update_password


  def self.update_password(username, new_password, new_password_conf, old_password)
    user = find_by_username(username)
    
      if new_password == new_password_conf && BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(old_password, user.salt) == user.encrypted_password
        new_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        new_pass = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(new_password, new_salt)
        user.update(encrypted_password: new_pass, salt: new_salt)
      else
        puts "Something went Wrong"
      end
    end
end
```

my **users_controller.rb**

```
  def change_password
     user = User.update_password( User.find(session[:user_id]).username,params[:password],params[:password_confirmation],params[:old_password])
  end
```

my **html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'change_password'}) do |f| %>
 <center><p> Παλιός Κωδικός Πρόσβασης</br> <%= f.password_field :old_password, placeholder: "Παλιός Κωδικός Πρόσβασης", name: "old_password"%> </p></center>
 <center><p> Νέος Κωδικός Πρόσβασης</br> <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Νέος Κωδικός Πρόσβασης", name: "password"%></p></center>
 <center><p> Επιβεβαίωση Νέου Κ.Πρόσβασης</br> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Επιβεβαίωση Νέου Κ.Πρόσβασης", name: "password_confirmation" %></p></center>
 <center><%= f.submit "Αποθήκευση", class: 'log_in_button' %><center>
<% end %>
```

**Console output**

```
Started POST "/users/change_password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-08-10 01:13:18 +0300
Processing by UsersController#change_password as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ORVdeLRZYMjP7XIMqligykYH7YqnjzprTpQnCl3G9XPj36hgEEcC+C/Y1F6Tp3QTOVrheaYD/SZM0BX+i3YERQ==", "old_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Αποθήκευση"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:76:in `change_password'
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["username", "mauras"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:36:in `update_password'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:41:in `update_password'
  User Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 AND "users"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["username", "mauras"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:41:in `update_password'
  User Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND "users"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["email", "asdas@adasd.com"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:41:in `update_password'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:41:in `update_password'
  Rendering users/change_password.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/change_password.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 365)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 608ms (Views: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 10770)
```

also try **user.save** still nothing,

Comment: If you change ``.update`` to ``.update!`` it will raise an error on failure and you'll get specific information about what's wrong (e.g., failing validation, etc.). Without that it's hard to help.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?

Comment: You can see which validations are failed with `user.errors.details` after you tried to update the user